# Make Styled components in React JS circular

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to build a component inside a wrapped styled component. The Styled component would be circular in shape and inside that I need to embed my component. Can someone please guide on what kind of styles I can apply to Styled component to make it circular ?

For example, before I had tried to make it a rectangular styled component and had given it below properties:

```
const IconContainer = styled.div`
 margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
  padding: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  justifycontent: center;
  align-items: center;
```

Comment: Answer: Found a solution on another stackoverflow link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69265763/putting-box-inside-circle-in-styled-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make it circular:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

Comment: + ``overflow: hidden;``